# Iterating through CSV file in python with certain conditions

Tags: python, csv

So im trying to iterate through csv file such as the following:

```
time    date    
25:07   40      
0:07    3       
0:67    1       
0:26    -1       
-1:26   4
```

and in the end i have to generate a list with the proper constraints. if its not in the proper constraint then the row wouldnt be generated in the end. 
the constraints are as this:
    1. Illegal time value structure (not HH:MM) and illegal time value (HH < 0 or HH> 23, MM < 0 or MM > 59). 
    2. Illegal date value (date < 1 or date > 31).

this is what i have tried:

```
atm_transaction_time_date = []
my_file = open("atm_file_time_date", "r")
reader = (csv.reader(my_file))

header = my_file.readline()

#to check for illegal time
for line in reader:
    if ':' not in (line[0]):
        continue
    elif int(line[0].split(':')[0]) < 0 or int(line[0].split(':')[0]) > 23:
        continue
    else:
        return (line[0].split(':')[0])
    if ':' not in (line[0]):
        continue
    elif int(line[0].split(':')[1]) < 0 or int(line[0].split(':')[1]) > 59:
        continue
    else:
        return (line[0].split(':')[1])

   #to check for illegal date
   if 0 > int(line[1]) > 31:
        continue
    else:
        return int(line[1])

   atm_transaction = (str(line[0]), int(line[1])
   atm_transaction_time_date.append(atm_transaction)

my_file.close()
return atm_transaction_time_date
```

but it still didnt work. this is the error message
        Error TypeError : unorderable types: str() < int() raised in function
        elif (line[0].split(':')[0] < 0) or (line[0].split(':')[0]) > 23:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this statement:

```
int(line[0].split(':')[0] < 0)
```

You are changing the type of the whole statement, instead of just line[0].split(':')[0]

It should be:

```
int(line[0].split(':')[0]) < 0 or int(line[0].split(':')[0]) > 23
```

From the error log, you can see you are comparing a string to an int, which is not allowed. It's just silly mistake that you did, as I can see you 
wrote it correctly for a similar statement below :)

This is the code:

```
import csv

atm_transaction_time_date = []
my_file = open("atm_file_time_date", "r")
reader = (csv.reader(my_file))

header = my_file.readline()

#to check for illegal time
for line in reader:
    if ':' not in (line[0]):
        continue
    elif int(line[0].split(':')[0]) < 0 or int(line[0].split(':')[0]) > 23:
        continue
    if ':' not in (line[0]):
        continue
    elif int(line[0].split(':')[1]) < 0 or int(line[0].split(':')[1]) > 59:
        continue

    if 0 > int(line[1]) > 31:
        continue
    atm_transaction = (line[0],int(line[1]))

    atm_transaction_time_date.append(atm_transaction)

print atm_transaction_time_date
```

return statement doesn't make any sense here. There is no function that you are calling. Continue statement passes to the next iteration of the loop. So, in case if and elif doesn't hold true, it means it's a valid date structure and you can append it to the list.

Comment: hey, i have fix it. but now its saying. Error UnboundLocalError : local variable 'line' referenced before assignment raised in function from    int(line[0].split(':')[0]) < 0 or int(line[0].split(':')[0]) > 23

Comment: It's working fine for me. Why are returning from the function and then checking if condition simultaneously

Comment: apparently. this is an invalid syntax. atm_transaction_time_date.append(atm_transaction)

Comment: so basically, what im trying to do is, if the constraints is not violated, then the return values from each condition will be put in the final list.

Comment: atm_transaction = Transaction(str(line[0]), int(line[1]), is Transaction a function here?

Comment: ohh sorry i fix it. its only meant to be atm_transaction = (str(line[0]), int(line[1])

Comment: so how would you suggest i fix it, so that it will only print out the list with the correct conditions?

Comment: ohh i see, thanks so much. ive only studied python. for a couple of weeks now :) greatly appreciate it

Comment: You have made a good progress Yusuf. Start debugging the code line by line, you will have exponential learning then :)

Comment: hey can i get your contacts. i have few questions about my python assignment. and im not able to get the chat function in stackoverflow. and i have 1 question per week limit here.